# Soft keyboard: Adjust_Resize pushing content offscreen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

i'm build a messaging like application, but I am having some issue with the keyboard pushing up content wrong.

What I want is for the content to be pushed upward exactly as much as the keyboard is tall, and for me to be able to freely scroll upward to view all the previous messages. Just like most messaging apps.

Here is my layout. I add layouts to the layout inside the scrollview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/open_messsages_constraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OpenMessages">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/messages_scroll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/linearLayout">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/allMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:backgroundTint="#f1f1f1"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:textColorLink="#000000" />


        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/sendMessageButton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            app:iconTint="#000000">

        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is before clicking the keyboard:
[image: Before I select the keyboard.]
Here is after. I can scroll downward sto view the message below, but I cannot scroll upward past this picture, so I am missing a message.
[image: After I click the keyboard.]

Comment: <activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>

Comment: @PrasanthS Tried it. Pan doesn't let any of the scroll content work, and it pushes my header off screen.

Comment: You can set marginbottom to your layout by taking difference of keyboard height and your layout height

Answer (score 0):

It's Work For Me :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

And Set Padding Of Your Recyclerview Bottom Padding.

```
padding:20
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work for me, per my images above.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `LinearLayout` for `allMessage` with below:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/allMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" // Add this line to view last messages
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </LinearLayout>
```